# Theme option not saved if in wp_editor() and html decoded

Tags: themes, tinymce, html, wp-editor

i'm trying to add `wp_editor()` to my theme-option page but it is not saved when html is decoded.

**so this is the issue:**

in the theme option page i successfully added a new option called `login_block_login_text`. usually i'd add this option as an array, but i wanted it to be a tinymce editor and not `textarea` so this is what i did:

```
<?php 
$editor_args = array(
    'textarea_name' => 'tie_options[login_block_login_text]'
);
$content = tie_get_option('login_block_login_text');
wp_editor( $content, 'login_block_login_text', $editor_args); 
?>
```

now the option is saved, but after refresh it is printed html encoded. this is the pre-saving encoding function for ALL theme options, which i guess causes it:

```
function tie_clean_options(&$value) {
     $value = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value));
}
```

BUT: if i add `htmlspecialchars_decode` to the first code, the option won't save at all. like this:

```
wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($content), 'login_block_login_text', $editor_args);
```

Thank you very much,

Itamar